# Wrapper Classes : Creating a python wrapper for a C project

Tags: python, c, wrapper

I am new to programming in python,but have programmed in C. I am working on a project called EtherDogs which is a network packet analyzer. How do I go about writing a python wrapper for the project ?

It would not be difficult if I had to do a C++ wrapper for it but how do I do it in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try a wrapper generator like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). Writing glue code by hand is repetitive and boring. Why not have the computer do the easy parts for you?

SWIG will take in your source files and a (minimal) interface specification. It'll produce Python proxy classes and C/C++ code. You compile the C/C++ code into a Python extension library, and then use it just like you would a pure-Python library. Under the hood, the proxy classes SWIG generates handle converting Python types to/from calls to the original C functions.

As an added bonus, wrapper generators (SWIG included) can usually create bindings for many different high-level languages with little or no additional effort on your part.